# List items dont center in div

Tags: html, css

A didn't want to make a separate div for the menu list items. Just stick with LI. But they keep sticking to the right top side.

How do I center #menuTop list?

The Code - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CBnfs

CSS

```
#header {
z-index: 1;
position: fixed;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 98.8%;
height: 60px;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
display: inline-block;
}
#header ul li {
margin-left:15px;
margin-top: 5px;
display:inline-block;
}
#menuTop {
height: 60px;
width: 500px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left: 500px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#menuTop a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
font-family: Open Sans;
}

#menuTop a:hover {
color: #00c4cc;
}
#menuTop ul li {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 20px
}
```

HTML

```
 <div id="menuTop">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#eventsImage">EVENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <ul id="socialIcons">
            <li id="facebook"><a id="facebook" href="#"></a></li>
            <li id="google"><a id="google" href="#"></a></li>
            <li id="twitter"><a id="twitter" href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="Our logo is here" id="logo"/></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: your question is really unclear, what are you expecting?

Comment: try in menuTop :   float:left;   and delete position absolute

Comment: http://codepen.io/jonigiuro/pen/JlwAg this seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `text-align: right` from:

```
#header ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;/*add also padding left to 0*/
    /*text-align: right; remove this*/
}
```

[**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xkGrF)

Answer (score 0):

remove:

```
position: absolute;
margin-left: 500px;
```

from #menuTop:

http://codepen.io/Fowler/pen/JsxmG

and also, if you want to center menuitems, add this:

```
#menuTop ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if #menutop is a child div of a main one, you should write this to the css of main div:

```
#main_div {position:relative;}
```

and this for #menutop :

```
#menutop {position:absolute; right:50%; margin-right:-250px; top:50%; margin-top:-30px;}
```